# Is nampaduvan's oath based on scripture?

Tags: scripture

From [here](http://anudinam.org/2013/12/10/the-story-of-nampaduvan-our-singer/) -

> It was the month of Karthigai (between November 15th and December
>   15th), a Shukla paksha Ekadasi (the Ekadasi that falls before the full
>   moon) day, our singer fasted the whole day and was awake that night
>   (jagratha vritham).  As usual, he left with his veena when he was
>   accosted by a Brahmarakshasa named Somasharma who was totally
>   famished. When a yagyam is not done as prescribed in the Vedas, the
>   doer becomes a Brahmarakshasa and Somasharma was one of them. He was
>   happy to find his prey. Nampaduvan, a devotee of Vishnu, did not fear
>   death and was actually happy to satisfy someone’s hunger but before
>   that he wanted to sing for the divya dampathis so he sought permission
>   to complete his last wish. Who would believe that once allowed to go a
>   human being would come back to be eaten by the Brahmarakshasa?
>
> Nampaduvan made a list of promises. Seventeen oaths were made but the
>   Brahmarakshasa was not convinced but the 18th one stumped him. The
>   18th oath was  ”if I fail to turn up, I will accept the punishment
>   given to one who equates Sriman Narayana with the demi-gods”.

Does scripture prescribe punishments for not declaring one or the other god supreme?

Comment: It is interesting that the vaishnavite website this is from has adopted the Hare Krishna denigration term "demi god".